# Is there a good graph (not charting) visualization API for .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, graph-theory

I've looked at [Microsoft GLEE](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2007/11/27/graphing-with-glee.aspx) (non-commerical use) and other libraries for drawing graphs, but I need a good commercial use graph API to show complex routes through the Internet.

I need to be able to show a large number of nodes and vertexes.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Graphviz resources page](http://www.graphviz.org/Resources.php) lists a project, [QuickGraph](http://www.codeplex.com/quickgraph), which may solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out Microsoft Research's NetMap

http://www.codeplex.com/NetMap

".NetMap is a pair of applications for viewing network graphs, along with a set of .NET Framework 2.0 class libraries that can be used to add network graphs to custom applications.

A network graph is a series of vertices (sometimes called nodes) connected by edges. See this Wikipedia article for an overview of network graphs.

.NetMap was created by Marc Smith's team at Microsoft Research."

Answer (score 2):

There is the [Piccolo Toolkit](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/jazz/); I haven't tried it yet but it looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

[Graph#](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/) at CodePlex

Answer (score 0):

Netron, a graphing library, that unfortunately died because the source got bought. Still, the last releases on SF are there: http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=69788&package_id=123851

Answer (score 0):

[ILOG Diagrammer](http://www.ilog.com/promotions/ppc/diagrammer/) offers network charting; actually, I haven't tried their Vis product, but am a happy user of their [Gantt](http://www.ilog.com/products/ganttnet/) product which works very well.

Answer (score 0):

OP,

The PowerShell blog entry you linked to has another link to a commercial version down in the comments. According to the commenter, it has been renamed Microsoft Automatic Graph Layout. Here is the direct link:
[Microsoft Automatic Graph Layout 2007](http://www.windowsmarketplace.com/details.aspx?view=info&itemid=6002737)